# Python Error: IndexError: string index out of range when getting every third letter of a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that prints a hidden message the user has input. The message should be discovered by reading every 3rd character in the input. For example if I input: "**p**ba**y**na**t**na**h**pr**o**ar**n**sm" it should print out the bolded letters, i.e. "python". But it comes up with this:

```
Message? pbaynatnahproarnsm

p y t h o n Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(msg[x], end= " ")
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here is the code

```
x = 0
msg = input("Message? ") 
for i in msg:
  print(msg[x], end= " ")
  x = x + 3
```

Comment: If you iterate over the whole string, which has length n, you'll end up accessing indices as far as 3*n.

Comment: This code prints the first letter, then the fourth, then the seventh, etc.  However the loop iterates once for _each_ letter in the string, so `[x]` quickly advances past the end of the string.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged by people downvoting you, you asked your question really well with the full output and error message and a clear paragraph about what you're trying to do and what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Python's [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) to get every third letter in a string:

```py
msg = "pbaynatnahproarnsm"
print(msg[::3])  # "python"
```

Comment: This is the ideal way to do it . But I suspect this is was a learning exercise and slices may not have been covered yet.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you've misunderstood how for loop works, the equlavent code with while loop:

```py
x = 0
msg = input("Message? ") 
while x < len(msg):
  print(msg[x], end= " ")
  x = x + 3
```

here is the equlavent for loop:

```py
msg = input("Message? ") 
for i in range(0, len(msg), 3):
  ## i will be 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, ... at each iteration
  c = msg[i]
  ## c will be the 0th, 3rd, 6th, ... character at each iteration
  print(c, end= " ")
```

even simpler

```py
msg = input("Message? ") 
print(' '.join([msg[i] for i in range(0, len(msg), 3)]))
```

the output is : **p y t h o n**

Answer (score 0):

`for i in msg:` iterates over each character in `msg`. You're using `x` starting at 0 and incrementing by 3 in every loop - so when you do `msg[x]`, the index `x` is 3 times the value of the index of the actual current character. Check by just printing `x` in your loop. When you're on the 8th char, with *index 7*, `x` is 21 which is longer than the length of `msg` (18).

To get the right output, the quickest/easiest way is using slice notation as per [Boris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65877834/1431750): `msg[::3]`. To get spaces, use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print(' '.join(msg[::3]))
```

If you want to use your method as a base, then increment `x` only by 1 (not 3) and print it only if its index is divisible by 3 (by checking that the [remainder](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) when divided by 3 is 0):

```py
x = 0
for i in msg:
    if x % 3 == 0:  # `%` gives the remainder
        print(i, end=' ')
    x += 1  # increment by 1, not 3

# p y t h o n
```

But that's a complicated way to go about it. (Using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the loop would be better; or just the slice notation, as mentioned.)